# How to explode dataframe column to multiple rows

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

schema: -

```
root
|--sentences:array
|  |--element:string
```

below is the sample element value of dataframe column it is nested dictionary and list object containing 100s of attributes as a string but for simplicity I have limited the attributes.

```
[{sentences=hello, id=1234, lang=eng, attributes={lang=eng, sid=789, number=[+10000000000]},
{sentences=hello2, id=1234, lang=eng, attributes={lang=eng, sid=789, number=[+10000000000]}]
```

expected output: -

```
row[0] = {sentences=hello, id=1234, lang=eng, attributes={lang=eng, sid=789, number=[+10000000000]

row[1] = {sentences=hello2, id=1234, lang=eng, attributes={lang=eng, sid=789, number=[+10000000000]}
```

Comment: good resource here : https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-explode-array-and-map-columns-to-rows/

Comment: @user238607 I have tried it but not able to get expected output

Comment: what did you try? what error did you get? put up an example here.